# How do you use route 53 to perform a reverse dns lookup?

Tags: route53, dns-lookup

We are using [Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) to map domains to IP address.  For example, if our website is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) , we use Route53 to setup mappings like:

```
service1.example.com --> 192.168.1.1
service2.example.com --> 192.168.1.2
service3.example.com --> 192.168.1.3
```

This is working great, because whenever we do `https://service2.example.com` it correctly maps to right IP address and returns a response from that service.

Is there a way I can use Route53 to look up the domain given the ip address? For example, if I enter `192.168.1.3`, then it would return `service3.example.com` ?

Is there a file in Route53 that can give me this information? Or is there a command I can run that will give me the domain given the IP address?

Comment: I don't think "performing a reverse DNS lookup" is the correct phrase as it implies you are wanting to query the route53 nameservers and see what it replies with for a reverse lookup **even if route53 is not authorative**.

Comment: What is the IP address you are wanting to provide reverse DNS for?  It is entirely probable that Route53 can't do this unless the IP range has been delegated to it which is somewhat unlikely.  Reverse lookup takes a totally different path through the DNS system to setting up a forward domain, and is likely not possible.   (It uses subdelegations of in-addr.arpa and PTR records, and is quite  a messy system with no direct connection to forward DNS)